# Why after executing set names utf8mb4, the column name changes to question mark?

Tags: mysql

Why after executing set names utf8mb4, the column name changes to question mark? See below:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%' ;
 +--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                 |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                  |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                    |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                  |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                  |
| character_sets_dir       | /opt/mysql/server-5.6/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
mysql> select '\U+1F600';
+------+
|      |
+------+
|      |
+------+
mysql> set names utf8mb4;
mysql> select '\U+1F600';
+------+
| ?    |
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

In my opinion, utf8mb4 is designed to support these emoji characters. Why changed to utf8mb4, the column name changed to question mark?

In addition, I copied the emoji character from website(http://getemoji.com/) , then pasted it in terminal.If I just type '\U+1F600' manually. See below:

```
mysql> select '\U+1F600' ;
+---------+
| U+1F600 |
+---------+
| U+1F600 |
+---------+
```

So I guess when I pasted it in terminal there is something happened implicitly. And this implicitly conversion( --> '\U+1F600') maybe could explain this phenomenpon.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be expected behaviour according to MySQL documentation, where metadata is declared to be stored in utf8 (the non-4byte version).

It is returned to the client as character_set_result (utf8mb4), however most likely your virtual column name is being stored at utf8 to be compatible and comparable with all other metadata and thus the 4-byte part of the character is lost even though it is not in a real table.

See here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-metadata.html

Comment: Thanks! May be you are right, but i'm not very sure.

Comment: I am pretty confident, the documentation says generally that all table metadata is stored specifically as utf8.  So it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Hey, I've found some new info of this question, maybe you are intrested. See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

I had found more info by using wireshark. See below:

1. Before executing set names utf8mb4
   [image]
2. After executing set names utf8mb4

[image]

In this case the server can't find a Charset number, so the column name become a question mark. And it seems which Charset number does not matter, just need it is not Unknow. If I execute set names latin1, the response packet info is:
[image]